# In Gradle, [how] should we target both Android and JRE?

Tags: java, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, travis-ci

re: [Consider updating JDK version for java-json-tools repos](https://github.com/java-json-tools/jackson-coreutils/issues/12)

In earlier editions of a Gradle-built Java library, it depended on a single version of Guava, and was putatively usable from Android. Since then, [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) has split its build/release into two flavors: JRE (JDK 1.8) and Android (JDK 1.7). Does this imply that this library now also needs to split into flavors and produce separate binaries? Or can one single SDK support both, and if we stick to JRE support it sould suffice?

If the answer is "more flavors", are there pointers to how to accomplish these multiple builds via Gradle / Travis?

I'm a fairly new maintainer, a Gradle novice and don't do Android development, so I'm sure I don't know the subtleties involved. It looks like the Android support previously was "it appears to not break people" rather than explicit testing, and I'd like to change that.

Found docs:

- Gradle

  - [Authoring Multi-Project Builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html), though I'm not sure whether this should really be a single project with additional Jar tasks.
- Travis

  - [Building an Android Project](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/android/), which is not currently being done, and anything would be in addition to the stock JRE testing.
  - [Testing Against Multiple JDKs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java/#testing-against-multiple-jdks)

Comment: RE: testing: In Guava, we run [Animal Sniffer](https://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/) to [test for API compatibility with Java 6](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/bdaa4683401dbe9c05e16e6cd2b1ba3caba7c961/android/pom.xml#L146-L171), which IIRC is supported all the way back to [Gingerbread](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers). (I base that on the fact that `NavigableSet`, a Java 6 API, was ["Added in API level 9"](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/NavigableSet). That's enough to support [basically everyone](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our general [recommendation](https://github.com/google/guava) is:

> If you need support for JDK 1.7 or Android, use the Android flavor.

The Android flavor is a subset of the JRE flavor, so if your code builds against the Android flavor, your users can substitute in the JRE flavor (by declaring a dependency on it), and your code will still work.

So we recommend depending on the Android flavor. (We do this for [at least one Android-compatible project of our own](https://github.com/google/truth/blob/7a58a45ba139f0b7e56bc2ffbf7733fa5351666c/pom.xml#L66).)

If you wanted, you *could* release multiple flavors of your own library. However, I wouldn't recommend it. We chose to do it by running Maven two separate times, but likely it could be done in a single Maven (or Gradle) run if that's easier. As you've seen, we differentiate between flavors by using the version number because [that was the least bad solution we could find](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NYGbfz56C0Oh4IGymXjeQUVK4FcRiqDbpc4vGLnDMrY/edit).